# What's a simple way for a parent node to reference a child node in a Syntax Tree?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

For a personal project, I'm building a simple HTML compiler. The compiler reads in a template file, parses it line-by-line, adding each line to a Syntax Tree as an individual node. Child nodes are denoted by tab indentation, similar to Python. Here's an example template file:

```
$doctype
    html {lang: $lang}
        head
            meta {charset: $encoding}
            title Hello World!
        body
            h1 {class: $test-class, foo: $bar} Hello world!
            p {class: $bar} How are you today? Is [span {class: $test-class} this] class total foobar?
```

For this example, the `doctype` tag would be the root of the tree, with `html` being its only child. `html` in turn has two children, `head` and `body`, each with its own list of children.

If you look at the `p` tag at the bottom, you'll see the line `[span {class: $test-class} this]`, using square brackets to denote inline HTML elements. That span would be represented in the tree as a child node of `p`.

Later on in the program's execution, I'll be outputting an HTML file based on the constructed Syntax Tree. I'm running into a mental block, however, when constructing that HTML file if there are inline HTML elements present.

My question to you: what is a simple way for a parent node to reference its child, specifically in a way so the block element can pull in data from its child inline element when outputting the compiled file?

Comment: In your approach, is it valid for a `[span]` to contain another `[span]`?

Comment: Yes, it'll simply create another node on the tree. At least, that's my thought.

Comment: Sounds good. How would the structure look if you had a page like `<p><p/>some normal text</p>`? Would `some normal text` appear on its own line, like `p\n p\n some normal text`? It seems like there are cases where inline text can't reasonably appear inline with its parent block, but the structure example seems to imply that there will be a tag at the beginning of each line (and that it's going to represent a block element). I think it's an interesting problem, so I hope you don't mind me asking you about it.